# Added poly-fill for .includes but still getting the error in one area despite being resolved in all other areas

Tags: javascript, reactjs, internet-explorer, polyfills

IE 11 triggers an `Object doesn't support property or method 'includes'` because it  isn't supported in IE11:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes#Browser_compatibility

You have to add the following polyfill for it to work:

```
if (!String.prototype.includes) {
  String.prototype.includes = function(search, start) {
    'use strict';
    if (typeof start !== 'number') {
      start = 0;
    }

    if (start + search.length > this.length) {
      return false;
    } else {
      return this.indexOf(search, start) !== -1;
    }
  };
}
```

I have added it to my `index.jsx` which has resolved the issue for any occurence of `.includes()` except for one and I'm not sure why.

I have this bit of JS in a React container:

```
removeInfectedFiles() {
    let { filesAccepted } = this.state;
    const { infected } = this.props.upload.data;

    this.setState({
        ...this.state,
        filesAccepted: filesAccepted.filter(
            file => !infected.includes(file.key)
        )
    })

    var filesInfected = [];

    _.map(infected, i => {
        filesInfected.unshift(
            <p key={ i }>{ i }</p>
        )
    });

    this.setState({
        filesInfected
    })

}
```

Works in every other browser except IE 11.

Before a file is written to the server, it is scanned for viruses. If a file has the server responds with a list of files that were infected which should be the `this.props.upload.data... and obviously doesn't write them to the server. This removes the filenames from the list of files that were successfully submitted.

Comment: You don't use babel-preset-env ?

Comment: It looks like I am not... I have `babel-preset-es2015`, `babel-preset-react`, `react-preset-stage-1`. Wasn't aware of it, but now that I am reading about it, sounds like I could have saved my self some time: https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-preset-env/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Array.prototype.includes()` is not the same as `String.prototype.includes()`. You need to include a pollyfill for the array method if `infected` is an array.

Comment: This resolved my issue, although using `react-preset-env` would have been the route to go from the beginning.

Comment: I agree about the `env` preset, saves so much time!